# Customize the djoser create user endpoint

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using djoser for auth purposes. I want to customize the create user end point of djoser. I have a User app. Here is my User model

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    account_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

and here is my serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from User.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'email', 'name', 'last_name', 'account_address', 'password')
```

and my User.urls.py looks like following

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import UserViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^account/', include('djoser.urls')),
]
```

and project's url.py is follwing

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users/', include('User.urls')),
    url(r'^advertisements', include('advertisements.urls')),
    url(r'^account', include('wallet.urls')),
]
```

but i am unable to create user with customized model instead when i go to user/account/create i see djoser's default create user view. Anybody please tell where I am doing wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Having in mind that you have set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to your `User` model.

Just import the Djoser User Registration Serializer And override it.

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer

class UserRegistrationSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'email', 'name', 'last_name', 'account_address', 'password', )
```

You can also override other things in the serializer like `create and update methods` in case if you want to customize it.

And in settings.py

```
DJOSER = {
    ...
    'SERIALIZERS': {
         'user_create': 'yourapp.serializer.UserRegistrationSerializer'
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: should DJOSER automatically pick this new serializer once the `DJOSER` object in the `settings.py` includes the `user_create` new serializer like in your example? or should one define a custom url that is connected to a custom view that uses the custom serializer? 

I have overridden the settings and serializers just like in your example but the Djoser registration endpoint shows me only the default email/password fields. How can my registration POST request also accept other fields that I define in my custom registration serializer  (e.g. last_name) that are already on my CustomUser model?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo It should automatically pick the new serializer. For serializer not picking up `last_name` fields, make sure that your meta Class is inheriting the Djoser UserRegsitrationSerializer metaclass as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I wanted to write a custom create method and it worked when I override user_create_password_retype and used mine since this is internally using the UserCreateSerializer from djoser

```
DJOSER = {
      ...
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        "user_create": "account.serializers.user_serializer.CustomUserCreateSerializer",
        "user": "account.serializers.user_serializer.CustomUserSerializer",
        "user_create_password_retype": "account.serializers.user_serializer.UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer",
    }
      ...
}
```

Other settings -
AUTH_USER_MODEL to your custom User model.