# Create related model with Djoser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am trying to override default user creation in Django. I am using Django Rest Framework and Djoser. I found very good tip for implementing it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49096275/9123009

but I have custom profile model, called: Userprofile that has OneToOneField relation to my custom User model.

Here is my serializer:

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usr_profile = UserprofileSerializer()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'usr_profile')
```

When I try to make following POST request to /auth/users/ endopoint:

```
{   
    "email": "adnan@test115.se",
    "password": "xxxxxx",
    "usr_profile": {
      "first_name": "adnan",
      "last_name": "erkoc",
      "cell_no": "23233"
    },
}
```

I keep getting an error that User.profile has to be Userprofile instance.

Comment: did you not need to override `from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer` like in the example you mention https://stackoverflow.com/a/49096275/9123009 to get it to work?

Comment: yes, I am using this line: `from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer`

Comment: 1) do you have a working example of all the settings.py, the custom serializers and whatever else that was done to get the custom serializers to work to share (such as GitHub gists)? 2) after you have got this to work and added all your fields to the field property of the Meta class, did the registration endpoint accept all the fields as expected? 

I find myself in the situation in which I have inherited the BaseUserRegistrationSerializers in a custom serializer, I have included this serializer in the DJOSER object of settings.py but the fields are still not accepted by the post request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not particularly related to Djoser but rather to DRF itself.

You can find the answer in DRF docs

[Writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usr_profile = UserprofileSerializer()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'usr_profile')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        usr_profile = validated_data.pop('usr_profile')
        user = UserModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **usr_profile)
        return album
```

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck with: from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer (from the answer I have referenced to)
and using it (class UserRegistrationSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):) 
inheriting from (serializers.ModelSerializer) solves the issue, but is there something I am loosing by not using djoser's UserCreateSerializer?