# Django Rest Framework - "Unable to create account" with Djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have some issue with User registration.

I'm using library Djoser by Sunscrapers.

During creating new User from Postman i get "Unable to create account" response.

[image]

In my terminal (docker) I get following informations:

```
ERROR: null value in column "country_id" violates not-null constraint

DETAIL: Failing row contains (53, null, , t, jaroslawpsikuta1@gmail.com, pbkdf2_sha256$180000$p2Q8c4Du3uLF$o56YHGCS0ZutasVhevPXl8rrMG/VYL..., , null, , , , 2020-03-10 10:06:48.053201+00, null, f).

STATEMENT: INSERT INTO "accounts_user" ("last_login", "email", "is_superuser", "is_active", "password", "first_name", "last_name", "date_of_birth", "description", "address", "phone", "created_at", "country_id") VALUES (NULL, 'jaroslawpsikuta1@gmail.com', false, true, 'pbkdf2_sha256$180000$p2Q8c4Du3uLF$o56YHGCS0ZutasVhevPXl8rrMG/VYLiyzTB6LrSY4ws=', '', '', NULL, '', '', '', '2020-03-10T10:06:48.053201+00:00'::timestamptz, NULL) RETURNING "accounts_user"."id"
```

It seems like Djoser don't see my request body, and it's trying to put empty or null values into database.
Till now, I tried following solution:
[Customize the djoser create user endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095424/customize-the-djoser-create-user-endpoint)
...but it didn't work.

code:

serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'description', 'address', 'phone', 'created_at', 'last_login', 'country']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```py
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = []
```

Do You have any ideas how to resolve it? Maybe I forgot something? Thank You for help :)
Best regards,

Comment: Youre passing in `country` instead of `country_id`?

Comment: post here code of front and back

Comment: Yes, it's how DRF serializer works. When I was creating new user without Djoser it works. It's not the issue, because as You see rest of body data is also empty.

Comment: it's too long so I will put it in my question :)

Comment: The rest of body data is not null though. you can see from the `STATEMENT` in your traceback that some values are being passed through. `STATEMENT: INSERT INTO "accounts_user" (...) VALUES (NULL, 'jaroslawpsikuta1@gmail.com', false, true, 'pbkdf2_sha256$180000$p2Q8c4Du3uLF$o56YHGCS0ZutasVhevPXl8rrMG/VYLiyzTB6LrSY4ws=', '', '', NULL, '', '', '', '2020-03-10T10:06:48.053201+00:00'::timestamptz, NULL) RETURNING "accounts_user"."id"`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
I needed to override User REQUIRED_FIELDS in model to make Djoser use it in serializer.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username_validator = None
    username = None
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'address', 'phone', 'country']
```

Comment: I changed nulled by default in one field from REQUIRED_FIELDS to null=True, made migrations and works